# Sylows theorem and P-sylow subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

If a group is of order $20$. Its factorisation is $2^2*5$. So, there are subgroups of order $2,4$ and $5$. 
Whether a $2$-Sylow subgroup means subgroup of order $2$ or $4$ ($2^2$) ??

From Sylow's third theorem i can say there is a normal subgroup of order $5$ ($1+5k|20$) and number of $2$-sylow subgroups are ($1+2k|20$) = $2$ . So there are $2$ subgroups order $4$.  Correct me, if i am wrong.

Comment: You can say what you want when you define a name for the sylow groups. Some authors say $p$-Sylow group and some authors say $p$-Sylow subgroup when they refer to the subgroups of prime power of highest order of $p$. Yes, there is exactly one $5$-Sylow group, which is normal. Next, the number of $2$-Sylow groups must divide $5$ and is of the form $1+2k$, hence the number of $2$-Sylow groups is $1$ or $5$.

Comment: I have always heard p-group for any subgroup having an order of a power of p and p-sylow subgroup for a p-group having maximal order. The 2nd sylow theorem then says every p-group is contained in a p-sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Sylow-p subgroups are defined to be subgroups of size *the largest* power of $p$ which divides the order of the group.

As for your workings, not quite. It is true that there is a subgroup of order $2$ by Cauchy's theorem, but you are trying to apply the Sylow theorems to a subgroup which is not a Sylow $p$ subgroup.

It is true that there is one Sylow-5 subgroup and it is indeed normal (why?).

You have that there is either $1$ or $5$ Sylow $4$ subgroups since 
$$
n_4=1+2k
$$
and 
$$
n_4\vert 5
$$

Comment: So, i can find number of subgroups of order $4$ , which is obtained by $1+4k$ . Can i say anything about number of subgroups of order $2$ (which is not a Sylow-p subgroup)   ??

Comment: $4$ is a prime?

Comment: ha you're right, just a difference in terminology then

Comment: So the conclusion is : a)The number of subgroups of order $4$ is $1$ or $5$ which we can calculate by $1+2k$ . Right ? b) We can only say there is a subgroup of order $2$ and cannot say anything about number of subroups of order $2$.

Comment: you can use the sylow theorems and the semidirect product to classify all groups of order 20, so you should, with a little work, be able to say a lot about the number of subgroups of order 2